# Retrieving Issue regarding stored procedures data type

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

1. I have written a stored procedure
2. Then I have written C# code

   ```
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString().Split(',')
   ```

   `ds` is my dataset which contains stored procedure retrieved from above ImportData (Column `SQLQueryName`))

The question is: I used string array for `strMendetory` and I need to find out data type of parameter of stored procedure from `strMendetory`. When I implement code for the same it returns `System.string` as usual (even it contains `DATETIME`).

Please give me suggestion on the same.

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddDepartments
        @DepartmentName VARCHAR(100),
        @DepartmentCode VARCHAR(100),
        @CompanyLocationID INT,
        @Details VARCHAR(100),
        @Flag BIT,
        @CreatedDateTime DATETIME,
        @MarkDeleted BIT,
        @AccessGroupMasterID INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Departments(DepartmentName, DepartmentCode, CompanyLocationID,  
                            Details, Flag, CreatedDateTime, MarkDeleted, 
                            AccessGroupMasterID)
    VALUES(@DepartmentName, @DepartmentCode, @CompanyLocationID, 
           @Details, @Flag, @CreatedDateTime, @MarkDeleted,
           @AccessGroupMasterID)    
END
GO

INSERT INTO ImportData(ImportItemName, ReferenceTableName, ImportFileName, 
                       SQLQueryTypeID, SQLQueryName, MarkDeleted)
VALUES('Department', 'Departments', 'ImportDepartments.xls',
       2, 'AddDepartments, @DepartmentName, @DepartmentCode, @CompanyLocationID, @Details, @Flag, @CreatedDateTime, @MarkDeleted, @AccessGroupMasterID', 0)
GO
```

C# code:

```
String[] strMendetory = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString().Split(',');
string columnValue="MynewValuToInsertinProcedure";

for (int columCounter = 1; columCounter < strMendetory.Count(); columCounter++)
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(strMendetory[columCounter], columnValue);
}
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: marc_s sir-  sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sqlparameter, you can specify the sql datatype. Here's the code example :

```
            SqlParameter[] param = {
                                        new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100),
                                        new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.Int),
                                        new SqlParameter("@param3", SqlDbType.DateTime)
                                   };

            //@param1, @param2, @param3 should match your parameters name in stored procedure

            param[0].Value = "test"; //pass the value to your parameter here
            param[1].Value = 2;
            param[2].Value = DateTime.Now;

            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

            foreach (SqlParameter x in param)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(x);
            }
```

Comment: @warheart1990 sir-In this condition parameter count is unknown and passing value also unknown. It would be better if you gives me another solution.